# How to remove/ add an attribute from a form input text fields using ng-click on a hypelink

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive that will remove the attribute disabled="disabled" from all input field contained in a form by clicking an edit link.

The problem I am facing is that when I click on the link, even though the directive code is being called, I am not passing the form fields, the only thing that the code has access to is the link element.

If anyone could help me to make this work, that would be sweet.

Here is the work I have done so far.

My html with directive as attribute:

```
<a title="Edit record" ab-toggle-fields ng-click="pc.toggle()">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

The toggle function in controller, I am not sure if I need this part, took it from an example:

```
vm.toggle = function () {
};
```

The directive code:

```
    (function (define, angular) {
    'use strict';

    define(function () {
        var toggleFieldsDirective = function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    'ngClick': '&'
                },                
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                    elem.bind('click', function () {

                        if (scope.ngClick){
                            var fields = elem.find(':input').not('button');
                            angular.forEach(fields, function (field) {
                                angular.element(field).removeAttr('disabled');
                            });
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        };
            return [
                toggleFieldsDirective
            ];
        });
})(define, angular);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the cleanest way is to simply use the ng-disabled directive on your inputs.  Set the value to some variable that gets toggled on the click of your link.  Like this:

```
<body>
  <a href="#" title="Edit record" ng-click="isDisabled = !isDisabled" ng-init="isDisabled=false">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>
  </a>
  <div>
    <input name="inputA" type="text" ng-disabled="isDisabled" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="inputB" type="text" ng-disabled="isDisabled" />
  </div>
```